# Remove noise from distance calculated from accelerometer data

Tags: filter-design, lowpass-filter, kalman-filters, digital-filters, noise-cancellation

I got distance calculated from accelerometer raw datas using double integral accelerometer.I attached the image below.But it shows noise with it.Please help me to remove this noise.

[image: distance vs time graph from accelerometer data]

Comment: Would it be possible to mention the specific equipment you used to obtain the data?

Comment: accelerometer to find acceleration

Comment: ...I appreciate that, but the question here is which accelerometer? Which model? How were the data obtained from the accelerometer? (mobile phone? Evaluation board? Other?)

Comment: I have only the raw,datas.So I dont know which type of accelerometer.It was integrated in an IMU sensor.

Comment: Can you please post the original data as it was obtained from the accelerometer? Not the integrated data to derive distance, the original data.